# Multiple queries in async/await (Error: IEnumerable does not contain ToListAsync())

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asynchronous, async-await

I would like to share that I went through other similar posts but the suggested solutions din't work for me and that's why I am creating a separate thread.I am trying to join the two results using Asynchronous programming in Entity Framework.I have three methods as below:

The method `PreprocessAppointment()` waits on other two methods `GetApptTask()` and `GetZoneTask()`

```
public async void PreprocessAppointment()
        {
            var task_1 = GetApptTask();
            var task_2 = GetZoneTask();
            await Task.WhenAll(task_1, task_2);
        }
```

The method `GetApptTask()` does not give any error.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<appointments>> GetApptTask(){

            var result = db.appointments.Where(d => d.appt_client_id == 15 && d.customer_id == 68009);

            return await result.ToListAsync();


        }
```

The method `GetZoneTask()`gives the following error. **`IEnumerable <zones> does not contain definition for ToListAsync()`.**

```
public async Task <IEnumerable<zones>> GetZoneTask()
        {
            var result = db.zones.Where(d => d.zone_client_id == "15").AsEnumerable().Distinct<zones>(new zones.Comparer());
            return await result.ToListAsync();
        }
```

I am unable to find out what might be causing this **error**.I am attaching the models structures as well for `appointments` and `zones` below. The only difference between the models apart from fields is the definition of `Comparer` class in `zones`.

**zones.cs**

```
public class zones
    {
        [Column(Order=0),Key]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string zone_client_id { get; set; }
        //public int zone_client_id { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 1), Key]
        [StringLength(5)]
        public string zip { get; set; }


        [StringLength(50)]
        public string zone { get; set; }

        public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<zones>
        {
            public bool Equals(zones x, zones y)
            {
                return x.zone_client_id == y.zone_client_id
                     && x.zip == y.zip
                     && x.zone == y.zone;
            }

            public int GetHashCode(zones obj)
            {
                return obj.zone_client_id.GetHashCode() ^
                      obj.zip.GetHashCode() ^
                      obj.zone.GetHashCode();   
            }
        }
    }
```

**appointments.cs**

```
 public  partial class appointments
    {

        public int appt_client_id { get; set; }

        public int customer_id { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int appt_id { get; set; }

        public DateTime appt_date_time { get; set; }

        [StringLength(200)]
        public string recording_uri { get; set; }

        public DateTime time_stamp { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string appt_status { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(5)]
        public string appt_type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the correct using statement? using System.Data.Entity

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`ToListAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.ToListAsync%60%601%28System.Linq.IQueryable%7B%60%600%7D%29) works on a `IQueryable<T>` only, when you turned it in to a `IEnumerable<T>` via `AsEnumerable()` you lost the ability to call it.

Because once you do `AsEnumerable()` you are working with a in memory collection anyway, just make it a list at that point.

```
var allZones = await db.zones.Where(d => d.zone_client_id == "15").ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
return allZones.Distinct<zones>(new zones.Comparer()).ToList();
```

The last `.ToList()` is optional. If you don't do it and you enumerate the returned IEnumerable multiple times you will run the `Distinct` multiple times. Doing a extra `.ToList()` makes it so it "remembers" the result of the `Distinct` instead of re-calculating it.

Comment: Could you please suggest what change should I make? Should I typecast result to IEnumerable?

Comment: I tried the solution you suggested but somehow the control never returns from var allZones = await db.zones.Where(d => d.zone_client_id == "15").ToListAsync();

Comment: @RudraniAngira Then I bet you have a `.Result` or a `.Wait()` somewhere higher up your callstack and is causing a deadlock. I added a `.ConfigureAwait(false)` which should fix it, but you really need to fix the deadlock.

Comment: Yes, One of the synchronous methods is calling PreprocessAppointment().Wait() . And in GetZoneTask() the status remains " Not yet computed "

Comment: @RudraniAngira [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: Synchronous methods should not be calling your async code. If you make a function async you must make it async all the way up the call stack. Read "[Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)", the rule you are violating is "Async all the way"

Answer (score 6):

Because ToListAsync() works on a IQueryable only, when you turned it in to a IEnumerable via AsEnumerable() you lost the ability to call it.
You can call .AsQueryable() on an IEnumerable sequence and it will return IQueryable.

For example:

```
private async Task<List<MyModelType>> GetAsyncListFromIEnumerable(
  List<MyModelIEnumerableType> mylist, 
  DateTime startDate, 
  DateTime endDate)
{
  var result = from e in mylist
               where e.StartDate >= startDate 
               && e.EndDate <= endDate
               select new MyModelIEnumerableType
               {
                 // Set of the properties here
               };
  return await result.AsQueryable().ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `GetApptTask` method the result at the return line is an `IQueryable` which has the extension method `ToListAsync` defined.

The call to `GetZoneTask` has the `AsEnumerable` which realizes the `IQueryable` into an `IEnumerable` which does NOT have the extension method `ToListAsync` defined.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<appointments>> GetApptTask()
{
    var result = db.appointments.Where(d => d.appt_client_id == 15 && d.customer_id == 68009);
    return await result.ToListAsync();  // result was an IQueryable here
}

public async Task <IEnumerable<zones>> GetZoneTask()
{
    var result = db.zones.Where(d => d.zone_client_id == "15")
                         .AsEnumerable()
                         .Distinct<zones>(new zones.Comparer());
    return await result.ToListAsync();   // here result is an IEnumerable because of the above call to AsEnumerable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Scott Chamberlain mentioned ToListAsync() works with

> [IQueryable;](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-6.2.0#overloads)

but you can use

> [FromResult()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netframework-4.8)

method instead of this.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<appointments>> GetApptTask()
{

   var result = db.appointments.Where(d => d.appt_client_id == 15 && d.customer_id == 68009);

   return await Task.FromResult(result);
 }
```