# How to use anonymous types in Cosmos Linq query

Tags: linq, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am strugging with using an anonymous type in Azure Cosmos Linq syntax.  This is the SQL I am trying to emit:

```
        //    @"SELECT        c.Profile.Customer.CompanyName,
        //                    c.Profile.Customer.CustomerID,
        //                    c.CustomFields.Status
        //                    FROM c"
        //    );
```

My Linq query looks like this but will not compile because the anonymous type doesn't match the type of the IQueryable

```
            IQueryable<CustomerDocument> query = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<CustomerDocument>()
            .Select(c => new
            {
                c.Profile.Customer.CompanyName,
                c.Profile.Customer.CustomerID,
                c.CustomFields.Status
            }).ToFeedIterator<CustomerDocument>();
```

If I omit the anonymous type the query runs fine, but it emits SELECT * FROM c which is very slow due to the size of the schema in the container.  If I run the SQL statement it is very fast, but obviously I don't want to maintain SQL text in my code if I can avoid it.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?  Not using Entity Framework in this project.

Comment: `var  query = ...` and `.ToFeedIterator()` without explicit type parameter.

Comment: This worked like a charm.  I still am struggling to find the way to acquire and console log the sql statement, which would be helpful, but it seems like this did the trick.  I could swear I already tried doing what you suggested, maybe I didn't get rid of the type on the ToFeedIterator method, I thought it was required with Cosmos

Comment: This is how C# works with anonymous types. Compiler can deduce which type of generic parameter to use from function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Try to use the `var` **or** `FeedIterator <CustomerDocument>` **&** `.ToFeedIterator()`

Agree with the `@Svyatoslav Danyliv` comments.

Below is the sample code from the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.getitemlinqqueryable?view=azure-dotnet#examples),

```cs
using (FeedIterator<CustomerDocument> query = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<CustomerDocument>().Select(c => new {
        // Required columns here...
         }).ToFeedIterator()) { 
        while (query.HasMoreResults) 
    { 
    foreach(var item in  await query.ReadNextAsync()) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(item.ColumnX); 
    } 
     } 
      }
```

***References:***

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/893#issuecomment-559760853

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57171695/18935775

Comment: Thank you Rajkumar, the issue was that I was adding the type to the Feed Iterator.