# LINQ Expression cannot be translated

Tags: c#, sql, linq, .net-core

I have written the below LINQ expression:

```
        var data = await _context.Occurrence
        .Include(o => o.Expense)
        .Where(o => 
            ((o.RepeatStart.Date - date.Date).TotalHours % o.RepeatInterval == 0) 
            ||
                o.RepeatYear == date.Year || o.RepeatYear < 0
                &&
                o.RepeatMonth == date.Month || o.RepeatMonth < 0
                &&
                o.RepeatDay == date.Day || o.RepeatDay < 0
                &&
                o.RepeatWeek == ISOWeek.GetWeekOfYear(date) || o.RepeatWeek < 0
                &&
                o.RepeatWeekDay == (int)date.DayOfWeek || o.RepeatWeekDay < 0
                &&
                o.RepeatStart.Date <= date.Date
        )
        .Select(e => e.Expense)
        .ToListAsync();
```

I am getting this error:
`could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable()`

However, I am not getting any runtime or compile time error(s). What have I done wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are invoking C#-specific functionality in the `WHERE` clause. Entity Framework is unable to convert it to pure SQL and is asking you to use `AsEnumerable()` to filter in the app instead of trying to convert it to SQL.

You should be able to get to work simply but complying:

```
   var data = await _context.Occurrence
    .Include(o => o.Expense)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(o => 
        ((o.RepeatStart.Date - date.Date).TotalHours % o.RepeatInterval == 0) 
        ||
            o.RepeatYear == date.Year || o.RepeatYear < 0
            &&
            o.RepeatMonth == date.Month || o.RepeatMonth < 0
            &&
            o.RepeatDay == date.Day || o.RepeatDay < 0
            &&
            o.RepeatWeek == ISOWeek.GetWeekOfYear(date) || o.RepeatWeek < 0
            &&
            o.RepeatWeekDay == (int)date.DayOfWeek || o.RepeatWeekDay < 0
            &&
            o.RepeatStart.Date <= date.Date
    )
    .Select(e => e.Expense)
    .ToList();
```

This however, will download the entire Occurence table. You should restructure it as following:

```
var data = await _context.Occurrence
    .Include(o => o.Expense)
    .Where(o => /* SQL-friendly calls only */)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(o => /* everything else */)
    .Select(e => e.Expense)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, trying this now but it seems `.ToListAsync() / await` fails. Need to use `.ToList()` and remove `await`.

Comment: Ah yes. My bad. This is nothing to worry about, however. It's local in-memory processing which will be fast. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38402901/4088472